# Zipping files with maximum size limit

Tags: python, zip

I have a few directories that contain a varying number of files, and I want to create zip files for each directory containing all of the files in the directory. This is fine for most of them, but one directory has significantly more files and zipping the entire thing would result in a 20GB+ file. I'd rather limit the maximum size of the zip file and split it into, say, 5GB parts. Is there an easy way to do this with Python? I'm using the zipfile module right now, but I'm not seeing a way to tell it to automatically split into multiple zips at a certain filesize.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use RAR insted of ZIP,
You can try this [RAR-PACKAGE](https://github.com/miebach/lib-rar-python)

```
from librar import archive
myRAR = archive.Archive("resultPath",base)
myRAR.add_file("FilePath")
myRAR.set_volume_size("5000000K") # split archive based on volume size 5 Gigabytes
```

Comment: OP requested a ZIP archive.  If an alternate archive format is acceptable, TAR (w/ compression) would be a more portable, free solution.  RAR is a proprietary archive file licensed by win.rar GmbH, ZIP and TAR are not.

Answer (score -1):

update:

that rar-package is outdated and does not work with python 3, but we have a better solution now:

```
rar a -m5 -v10m myarchive movie.avi
```

It will compress movie.avi and split it into 10 MB chunks (-v10m), using the best compression ratio (-m5)

more info:
https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/compress-with-rar-and-split-into-multiple-files/